# React how to send object to onClick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

How can I send object to the onClick event in react? I have a list of items where every item is related to the object in state object. It is created in method getList() in the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function ItemsList() {

    /*constructor(props)
    {
        //super(props);
        //this.state.list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
    }*/

    let state = {
        list: [
            {id:1, name: 'aaa'}, {id: 2, name: 'bbb'}, {id: 3, name: 'ccc'}
        ]
    }

    return (
        <div> 
            {getList()}
        </div>
    )

    function getList()
    {
        let items = state.list.map(item => { return (<li key={item.id} onClick={handleClick} className={item.id > 5 ? 'green' : 'red'}>item: {item.name}</li>) });
        return <ul>{items}</ul>
    }


    function handleClick(event) {  // Here I want to get item + event object as params
        alert(event);
    }
}

export default ItemsList;

if (document.getElementById('itemsList')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<ItemsList />, document.getElementById('itemsList'));
}
```

How can I send item object to onClick event?

Comment: `onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, item)}`

Comment: Yes I have it. Thaks.

Answer (score 0):

Oh as I wrote the question I tried call anonymouse function from onclick and it works

```
onClick={e => {handleClick(item, e)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

just adding one more way:-

```
const myCustomOnClick = (e: Event || EventArgsType): clickType => handleClick(item,e)
```

`onClick={this.myCustomOnClick}` -- class component

`onClick={myCustomOnClick}` -- functional or hooks or composable component